# Space of piecewise continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is not complete under 2 norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to understand that $\check{C}[0,1]$ is not complete under  the 2 norm and no Hilbertspace under $(f,g)=\int f\overline{g}$

Suppose $\check{C}[0,1]$ being the space of piecewise continuous functions on $[0,1]$. I found the answer in another script , where they say it is clear by looking at $$f_{n}(t) = (-1)^n \text{for} \ 0\le t\le 2^{-n}$$

$$f_{n}(t)=(-1)^k \ \text{for} \ 2^{-(k+1)}<t\le 2^{-k}, \text{where} \ k=n-1, n-2, \ldots, 2,1,0$$

I have troubles understanding this answer/construction, It needs to be continuous on $[0,1]$, by letting $n\to \infty$ the $(f_n)$ would end up being -1 and 1 at the same time so continuity isn't given at 0?

Before checking the scalarproduct properties for the hilbertspace, doesn't a hilbertspace require completeness? So the second partial question would directly follow from the first one,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question: Yes, the second partial question follows from the first one.

For the first question: Well, that is the idea, but it is not a proof. You cannot argue by looking at the pointwise limit - it does not even exist. First you would have to convince yourself that $(f_n)_n$ is indeed a Cauchy sequence in your space (this is easy). But then you would have to prove that it does not converge, so there is no piecewise continuous function such that the sequence converges to it in the 2-norm. If you are allowed to use that $L^2[0,1]$ is the completion of the space, then you can identify the $L^2$-limit and show that it cannot be represented as a piecewise continuous function (which shows that $\check{C}[0,1]$ is not closed in $L^2[0,1]$, so it cannot be complete).

By hand you could do it as follows: Assume the sequence has a limit $f$ in your space. Then $1_{]2^{-m},1]} f_n$ converges to $1_{]2^{-m},1]} f$ (proof?), and also it is eventually constant in $n$, so it converges to $1_{]2^{-m},1]} f_m$. But this means $f = f_m$ on $]2^{-m},1]$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, so
$$f(x) = (-1)^k, \text{ if } 2^{-(k+1)} < x \leq 2^{-k}.$$
This contradicts the fact that $f$ must be continuous in a small neigborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very helpful answer.